# How to connect to a MySql database server created using puphet configuration?

Tags: mysql, vagrant, virtualbox, puppet, netbeans-8

I recently created a vagrant virtual box for web development and I was able to connect to the server instance of Apache in the virtual machine, but I'm having trouble connecting to the MySql server.

I gave a user and password when I created the configuration on puppet, but I'm still not able to connect when giving those credentials.

I am using the netbeans IDE as my main development tool and connecting to all servers using it.

I appreciate any help that anyone can give. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your host and ports are correct.

Comment: How can I check my ports for my virtual box setup for the MySql? As well as the host?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What eventually made it work for me was executing

```
sed -i "s/^bind-address/#bind-address/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
mysql -u root -proot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

First command comments out the bind-address config and after than ensuring that you have permissions with the root user

This example help me to debug: https://github.com/AlexDisler/mysql-vagrant